# Linkage Table: Technical name given to table storing associations?

Tags: sql, foreign-key-relationship

Title pretty much sums it up.

Is there a technical name given to a table that stores primary key from two separate tables to create a linkage.

i.e.

```
car ( id, manufacturer, model, year, vin),  
passenger ( id, name ),  
linkage_table ( car, passenger )
```

Where car stores value of the `id` column from the car table and passenger stores the value of `id` column from the passenger table.

```
SELECT c.*, p.*  
 FROM car c, passenger p, linkage_table l  
 WHERE c.id = 15   
 AND c.id = l.car  
 AND p.id = l.passenger
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), and is used in a [Many-to-Many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship.